# Trouble In Create the Table in Oracle SQL DB

Tags: sql, database, oracle

Hi I have already created the Table and made the Transaction for it. Now I am having trouble in creating a view for The table. I tried to Find the error  and kept on doing it but still not going well.

I'm new to SQL and Stack overflow.
The following Code is Creating the Table and the Transaction, followed by the View that has the error.

```
**Create Table**


create TABLE employee

(
EmployeeID varchar2(10) PRIMARY KEY,

EmployeeName varchar2(30) NOT NULL,

Phone number(10) NOT NULL,

JobTitle varchar2(30) NOT NULL

);


create TABLE Airplane

(

AirplaneID varchar2(10) PRIMARY KEY,

Capacity number NOT NULL,

Modle varchar2(10) NOT NULL

);


create TABLE Route

(

FlightID varchar2(10) PRIMARY KEY,

Origin varchar2(20) NOT NULL,

Destination varchar2(20) NOT NULL,

ETD number(10) NOT NULL,

ETA number(10) NOT NULL

);


create TABLE Customer

(

CustomerID varchar2(10) PRIMARY KEY,

CustomerName varchar2(10) NOT NULL,

PhoneNumber number NOT NULL

);


create TABLE Maintenance

(

MaintenanceID varchar2(20) PRIMARY KEY,

MaintenanceDate date NOT NULL,

AirplaneID varchar2(10) NOT NULL,

EmployeeID varchar2(10) NOT NULL,

Location varchar2(30) NOT NULL,

FOREIGN KEY (AirplaneID) REFERENCES Airplane(AirplaneID),

FOREIGN KEY (EmployeeID) REFERENCES employee(EmployeeID)

);

create TABLE Flight

(

FlightID varchar2(10),

FlightDate date,

AirplaneID varchar2(10),

ATD number(10) NOT NULL,

ATA number(10) NOT NULL,

--FOREIGN KEY (FlightID) REFERENCES Flight(FlightID),  --check you can't do this:

FOREIGN KEY (AirplaneID) REFERENCES Airplane(AirplaneID),

CONSTRAINT PK_FlightID PRIMARY KEY (FlightID,FlightDate)

);

create TABLE Reservation

(

ReservationID varchar2(20) PRIMARY KEY,

CustomerID varchar2(10) NOT NULL,

FlightID varchar2(10) NOT NULL,

FlightDate date NOT NULL,

Fare float,

PaymentMethod varchar2(20),

CardNumber number(30) NOT NULL,

ExperationDate date,

check (PaymentMethod = 'Cash' OR PaymentMethod ='Credit' OR PaymentMethod 

='Cheque'),

FOREIGN KEY (CustomerID) REFERENCES Customer(CustomerID),

FOReIGN KEY (FlightID,FlightDate) REFERENCES Flight(FlightID,FlightDate)

);

create TABLE CrewAssignment

(

EmployeeID varchar2(10),

FlightID varchar2(10),

FlightDate date NOT NULL,

Role varchar2(20) NOT NULL,

FlightHour number(10) NOT NULL,

FOReIGN KEY (FlightID,FlightDate) REFERENCES Flight(FlightID,FlightDate),

FOReIGN KEY (EmployeeID) REFERENCES employee(EmployeeID) ,

CONSTRAINT PK_CrewAssignment PRIMARY key (FlightID,FlightDate,EmployeeID)

);
```

**Transaction**

```
insert into Route (FlightID, Origin, Destination, ETD, ETA) values

('FBN001', 'Perth', 'Singapore', '1100', '1600');

insert into Airplane (AirplaneID, Capacity, Modle) values

('FH-FBT', '350', 'Boeing767');



insert into Flight (FlightID, FlightDate, AirplaneID, ATD, ATA) values

( 'FBN001', '20 october 2014', 'FH-FBT', '1105', '1555');

insert into Flight (FlightID, FlightDate, AirplaneID, ATD, ATA) values

( 'FBN001', '20 october 2014', 'FH-FBT', '1105', '1555');

insert into Employee (EmployeeID,EmployeeName,Phone,JobTitle) values

('01', 'Martha McGee','123456', 'Pilot');

insert into Employee (EmployeeID,EmployeeName,Phone,JobTitle) values

('02','Dorothy McDonald','2211', 'Co-Pilot');

insert into Employee (EmployeeID,EmployeeName,Phone,JobTitle) values

('03','Albert','1122', 'Engineer');

insert into Employee (EmployeeID,EmployeeName,Phone,JobTitle) values

('04','Kathy Kelly','5544', 'HeadSteward');

insert into Employee (EmployeeID,EmployeeName,Phone,JobTitle) values

('05', 'Ornella', '3123', 'Steward');

insert into CrewAssignment (EmployeeID,FlightID,FlightDate, Role, FlightHour) values

('01','FBN001', '20 October 2014', 'Flight','5');

insert into CrewAssignment  (EmployeeID,FlightID,FlightDate, Role, FlightHour) values

('02','FBN001', '20 October 2014', 'Flight','5');

insert into CrewAssignment  (EmployeeID,FlightID,FlightDate, Role, FlightHour) values

('03','FBN001', '20 October 2014', 'Flight','5');

insert into CrewAssignment  (EmployeeID,FlightID,FlightDate, Role, FlightHour) values

('04','FBN001', '20 October 2014', 'Non-Flight','0');

insert into CrewAssignment  (EmployeeID,FlightID,FlightDate, Role, FlightHour) values

('05','FBN001', '20 October 2014', 'Non-Flight','0');

insert into Customer (CustomerID,CustomerName,PhoneNumber) Values

('01', 'John Smith', '81393'); 




insert into Reservation (ReservationID,CustomerID,FlightID, FlightDate,Fare,PaymentMethod,CardNumber, ExperationDate) values
('01' , '01', 'FBN001','20 October 2014', '100' , 'Cash' , '44444' , '21 Feb 2019'); 







insert into Employee (EmployeeID,EmployeeName,Phone,JobTitle) values
('06','Laurence Schreiner','007', 'Supervisor');

insert into Maintenance (MaintenanceID,MaintenanceDate, EmployeeID, AirplaneID, Location) values
('004', '21 October 2014', '06', 'FH-FBT', 'Melbourne Airport');
```

**Creating View**

ViewA:
   All flight reservations made by John Smith including, for those flights that have flown, the duration of the flight

```
Create View ViewA as 
Select Reservation.ReservationID,Flight.FlightID,Flight.FlightDate, Flight.ATA - Flight.ATD as DurationofFlight 
from Reservation, Customer, FLight
where Customer.CustomerName = 'John Smith' and
Customer.CustomerID = Reservation.CustomerID and
Reservation.FlightID = Flight.FlightID and
Reservation.FlightDate = Flight.FlightDate;
```

ViewB:
   Number of unreserved/available seats on FBN001 on 20th October 2014.

```
Create view ViewB as 
Select Airplane.Capacity, count(Reservaion.ReservationID)
from Airplane,Reservation
where FlightID='FBN001' and FlightDate='20 October 2014'
and Flight.AirplaneID = Airplane.AirplaneID
and Flight.FlightID = Reservaton.FlightID
and Flight.FlightDate=Reservation.FlightDate;
```

ViewC:
   Total hours flown EVER, for crew of the FBN001 on 20th October 2014.

```
Create vire ViewC as 
select EmployeeID, sum(FlightHour)
from CrewAssignment
where CrewAssignment.EmployeeID in
(select EmployeeNO from CrewAssignment
where FlightID = 'FBN001' and FlightDate = '20 October 2014')
group by EmployeeID;
```

ViewE:
   Maintenance history for FH-FBT including the date and location of maintenance episode, whether or not the maintenance was scheduled or not, and the name and phone number of the supervising employee.

```
  Create view ViewE as 
select Maintenance.MaintenanceDate, Maintenance.Maintenance.Location,
Employee.EmployeeName,Employee.EmployeeName 
from Maintenance, Employee
where Maintenance.AirplaneID = 'FH-FBT' and
Maintenance.EmloyeeID = Employee.EmployeeID;
```

**Here the Error that i got for Each Table**

View A

```
Error starting at line : 157 in command -
create View ViewA as 
Select Reservation.ReservationID,Flight.FlightID,Flight.FlightDate, Flight.ATA - Flight.ATD as DurationofFlight 
from Reservation, Customer, FLight
where Customer.CustomerName = 'John Smith' and
Customer.CustomerID = Reservation.CustomerID and
Reservation.FlightID = Flight.FlightID and
Reservation.FlightDate = Flight.FlightDate
Error at Command Line : 157 Column : 13
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00955: name is already used by an existing object
00955. 00000 -  "name is already used by an existing object"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

View B

```
Error starting at line : 166 in command -
create view ViewB as 
Select Airplane.Capacity,count(Reservaion.ReservationID)
from Airplane,Reservation
where FlightID='FBN001' and FlightDate='20 October 2014'
and Flight.AirplaneID = Airplane.AirplaneID
and Flight.FlightID = Reservaton.FlightID
and Flight.FlightDate=Reservation.FlightDate
Error at Command Line : 172 Column : 5
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "FLIGHT"."FLIGHTDATE": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

ViewC

```
Error starting at line : 177 in command -
create view ViewC as 
select EmployeeID, sum(FlightHour)
from CrewAssignment
where CrewAssignment.EmployeeID in
(select EmployeeID from CrewAssignment
where FlightID = 'FBN001' and FlightDate = '20 October 2014')
group by EmployeeID
Error at Command Line : 178 Column : 20
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00998: must name this expression with a column alias
00998. 00000 -  "must name this expression with a column alias"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

ViewE

```
Error starting at line : 186 in command -
create view ViewE as 
select Maintainence.MaintainenceDate, Maintainence.maintainence.Description,
Employee.EmployeeName,Employee.EmployeeName 
from Maintenance, Employee
where Maintenance.AirplaneID = 'FH-FBT' and
Maintenance.EmloyeeID = Employee.EmployeeID
Error at Command Line : 191 Column : 1
Error report -
SQL Error: ORA-00904: "MAINTENANCE"."EMLOYEEID": invalid identifier
00904. 00000 -  "%s: invalid identifier"
*Cause:    
*Action:
```

Comment: You should edit your question and identify the view you are having a problem with.  You should also mention the error you are getting.

Comment: Sorry man i just first time posting here. i will edit and include the error.

Answer (score 0):

You are using `Creater` instead of `create` change from `creater` to `create` and it should work. Please Check your speling also at one point you have `create vier` instead of `create view`

```
Create view ViewE as 
select Maintainence.MaintainenceDate, Maintainence.maintainence.Description,
Employee.EmployeeName,Employee.EmployeeName 
from Maintenance, Employee
where Maintenance.AirplaneID = 'FH-FBT' and
Maintenance.EmloyeeID = Employee.EmployeeID;
```

sum(FlightHour) -this must be named with an alias

invalid identifier - the column does not exist

name already in use by existing object - use `create or replace view`

Any other - please read the sql manuals before trying something serious as this;

Comment: Just try bro still got error. i will edit and post my error for each view

Comment: Done i just Edit and upload inside the question for the error that i have been encounter.

Comment: See my edits, you will get the idea. I suggest you use google and see how so many examples you get of these errors.

Comment: Alright man! Thanks for the advice. i go and try out and trouble shoot the error

Answer (score 0):

There are many issues. A few are:

1. `ViewB` references `FLIGHT` in the `WHERE` clause, but `FLIGHT` is not in the `FROM` clause.
2. The statement for `ViewC` says `create vire` instead of `create view`.
3. `ViewC` references `employeeno` from `CrewAssignment`, but no such column exists.
4. In `ViewC` you are using an aggregate function without an alias, so the database can't figure out what to name the column.
5. In `ViewE`, `EmployeeId` is missing the "p".
6. `ViewE` references `Maintainence.maintainence.Description`. Specifying the table name twice is invalid. Additionally, there is no `Description` column in the `Maintainence` table.

These are all extremely basic problems that should be solvable using rudimentary troubleshooting skills. Posting this question demonstrates a total lack of effort to solve these problems.

Comment: Ya man. sorry for my careless mistake. I'm new to SQL and here. Anyway i mange to correct my View already. Thx for the Adive.

Answer (score 0):

```
View A:
create view ViewA as
select Reservation.ReservationID, Flight.FlightID, Flight.FlightDate, Flight.ATA - Flight.ATD as DurationOFFlight
from Reservation, Customer, Flight
where Customer.CustomerName = 'John Smith' and
Customer.CustomerID = Reservation.CustomerID and
Reservation.FlightID=Flight.FlightID and
Reservation.FlightDate=Flight.FlightDate;

View B:

create view ViewB as
select Airplane.Capacity - Reservation.ReservationID
as RemainingSeats
from Airplane, Reservation, Flight
where
Flight.FlightID = 'FBN001' and Flight.FlightDate='20 October 2014'
and Flight.AirplaneID = Airplane.AirplaneID and
Flight.FlightID = Reservation.FlightID and
Flight.FlightDate = Reservation.FlightDate;


View C:

create view ViewC as
select EmployeeID, sum(FlightHour) as Total_Hours
from CrewAssignment
where CrewAssignment.EmployeeID in
(select EmployeeID from CrewAssignment
where FlightID='FBN001' and FlightDate='20-10-2014')
group by EmployeeID;

View D:

create view ViewD as
select JobTitle, sum(FlightHour) as Total_Hours
from CrewAssignment
where CrewAssignment.EmployeeID in
(select EmployeeID from CrewAssignment
where FlightID='FBN001' and FlightDate='20-10-2014' and EmployeeID= '123456')
group by JobTitle;


View E: 

create view ViewE as
select Maintenance.MaintenanceDate,Maintenance.Location, 
Employee.EmployeeName,Employee.Empphone from Maintenance,Employee 
where Maintenance.AirplaneID = 'FH-FBT' and Maintenance.EmployeeID = Employee.EmployeeID;
```